# Algorithm time complexity types explaining

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I read about time complexity of an algorithm and I don't know if I understand... All examples below are created in C++. Please lets me know if I am wrong:

`O(1)`:

```
int k;
k = 0;
```

`O(n)`:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   k[i] = i%10;
}
```

`O(n^2)`:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      k[j] = i%10;
   }
}
```

`O(n^k)`(k is a known number - there are `k` for statements):

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
   for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      .......
      for(int f=0; f<n; f++) {
         k[j][f] = p%10;
      }
      .......
   }
}
```

1. What is `O(k^n)`? What is `O(log n)` and `O(n * log n)`? Please take me an algorithm (code) example for each one.
2. Am I wrong with examples above?

Comment: [Binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is a classic example of a (worst case) `O(logN)` algorithm

Comment: Why -1? Please explain me to edit the question to make it better.

Comment: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: It's probably -1 because it's a homework or test question.

Comment: @dbillz [Homework questions are not off-topic if asked properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). I think the downvotes are because this is quite a broad question. There are several requests here a) showing a bunch of examples of code snippets and their complexity b) explaining the difference between space and time complexity. As shown in the link shared by awesomeyi this is quite well-documented if you search for the first request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many explanations on the internet, Google for "big O notation". A simple introduction you'll find at https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Examples:

- O (k^n): Generating all words of n characters
- O (log n): Searching in a sorted list of n elements by repeatedly halving it
- O (n log n): Sorting a list with e.g. the Quicksort algorithm

Space complexity is not tied to time complexity. Searching a list doesn't cost space, but it does cost time. You can use the "Big O" notation for any function, so consumed time as function of n, or consumed space as function of n.

All your examples are correct.

Answer (score 1):

1.
O(k^n): List all binary strings length n ( O(2^n) )

O(logn): Binary search is a simplest example

O(nlogn): Sorting Algorithms such as quicksort, heapsort....

2. You're right
3. No, space complexity is different from time complexity
   Example: If you store your data into a 2-dimension array, they you have a O(n^2) space complexity but you only need one for loop through n elements then your algorithm has a O(n) time complexity.
   Note: Use of O(n^2) and O(n) in my example is not completely right, we better use theta(n^2) and theta(n)

Hope it's helpful.